# Python Pivot Table margins=True not summing well

Tags: python, pandas, pivot-table

I have the below code:

```
import pandas as pd
df=pd.read_csv("https://www.dropbox.com/s/90y07129zn351z9/test_data.csv?dl=1", encoding="latin-1")
pvt_received=df.pivot_table(index=['site'], values = ['received','sent'], aggfunc = {  'received' : 'count' ,'sent': 'count'}, fill_value=0, margins=True) 
pvt_received['to_send']=pvt_received['received']-pvt_received['sent']
column_order = ['received', 'sent','to_send']
pvt_received_ordered = pvt_received.reindex_axis(column_order, axis=1)
pvt_received_ordered.to_csv("test_pivot.csv")
table_to_send = pd.read_csv('test_pivot.csv', encoding='latin-1')
table_to_send.rename(columns={'site':'Site','received':'Date Received','sent':'Date Sent','to_send':'Date To Send'}, inplace=True)
table_to_send.set_index('Site', inplace=True)
table_to_send
```

Which generate this table:

```
      Date Received       Date Sent       Date To Send
Site            
2         32.0             27.0           5.0
3         20.0             17.0           3.0
4         33.0             31.0           2.0
5         40.0             31.0           9.0
All       106.0            106.0          0.0
```

But this parameter margins=True is not giving correct result of total of each columns. For instance, Date Received should be 125 instead of 106, Date Sent should be 106 (it is correct) and Date To Send should be 19 instead of 0.0 (zero). Question: What am I supposed to change to get correct numbers? Also, there is lack on All that should do a sum of each row. Thanks a lot in advance.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It seems from your code that you create the `Date To Send` after the pivot table is constructed so it's just giving you the result of: `106.0 - 106.0`.  Also, they way margin values are [calculated](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/dc0674d66c1e8cd1917a6ec28f0b5a6d3e23c5e6/pandas/core/reshape/pivot.py#L132) with the default `dropna=True` after grouping means that any row with a `NaN` or `NaT` will be dropped.  Setting `dropna=False` should fix this problem.

I refactored your code to convert the `received` and `sent` columns to `date_time` format before creating the pivot table and the `to_send` column.

```
df2 = pd.read_csv(
         "https://www.dropbox.com/s/90y07129zn351z9/test_data.csv?dl=1"
         ,encoding="latin-1")
df2['received'] = pd.to_datetime(df2['received'])
df2['sent'] = pd.to_datetime(df2['sent'])
```

Then create the pivot table, which was originally intended.

```
pvt_received = df2.pivot_table(index=['site'], values=['received','sent'],\
    aggfunc='count', margins=True, dropna=False)

pvt_received['to_send'] = pvt_received['received'] - pvt_received['sent']
pvt_received.rename(columns={'site':'Site'
                             ,'received':'Date Received'
                             ,'sent':'Date Sent'
                             ,'to_send':'Date To Send'}
                             ,inplace=True)
pvt_received

        Date Received   Date Sent   Date To Send
Site            
2       32              27          5
3       20              17          3
4       33              31          2
5       40              31          9
All     125             106         25
```

Comment: Values from to_send are wrong, Date To Send should be 19 instead of 106.